# Operator binding in Python

Tags: python

I have a containery object something like this:

```
class foo(object):
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value
  def __eq__(self,other):
    return self.value == other
```

Which I can use like this:

```
>>> var = foo(4)
>>> var == 4
True
>>> var == 3
False
>>> # So far so good
>>> var == foo(4)
True
>>> var == foo(3)
False
>>> # Huh
```

My question is: what is happening that allows this to magically "just work"? How does Python bind the `==` operator inside `__eq__` so that the `value` member of both sides is compared?

Comment: Not so strange? `3 != 4`? `var` is effectively `4`, so comparing it to anything other than `4` or `foo(4)` should return False?

Comment: it's operator overloading in python: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading1.txt

Comment: There's whole official documentation on magic methods: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an `__eq__` method returns `NotImplemented` for a given argument, Python will try the same test in reverse. So `x == y` will try `x.__eq__(y)` first, if that returns the `NotImplemented` singleton, `y.__eq__(x)` is tried.

This applies to the comparison *inside* your `__eq__` method as well; you are essentially comparing:

```
self.value == other
```

which is:

```
4 == other
```

which is:

```
4.__eq__(other)
```

which returns `NotImplemented`:

```
>>> var = foo(4)
>>> (4).__eq__(var)
NotImplemented
```

So Python tries `other.__eq__(4)` instead, which returns `True`.

Comment: My local implementation of Python gives `AttributeError: 'int' has no attribute '__eq__'`. I guess any exception prompts the reversal of the comparison? Do similar things happen if a class implements `__gt__` but not `__lt__`?

Comment: So when comparing `var == foo(4)` this get's reduced to `var.value == foo(4)` Which should raise a notimplemented error. Does it then try the reverse as `foo(4) == var.value` or `foo(4) == var`? would it try the second if the first also raised a notimplemented error?

Comment: Note that things are slightly different for methods which have reflected bindings in the object model -- e.g. `__add__`.  In that case, I believe the call order is `__add__(x, y)` -> `__radd__(x, y)`

Comment: @rophl: I was using Python 3. Not implementing an `__eq__` method at all in Python 2, means falling back to `__cmp__`.

Comment: @mgilson: Indeed, but rich comparisons explicitly do *not* have reverse versions.

Comment: @M4rtini: `var.__eq__(foo(4))` is called, this then executes **another** comparison, `var.other == foo(4)`. Python tries that separately, so first `var.other.__eq__(foo(4))` returning `NotImplemented`, then `foo(4).__eq__(var.other)`, returning `True`. So the *outermost* `var.__eq__(foo(4))` call does not return `NotImplemented`, it returns `True`.

Comment: `foo(4) == var` would be the reverse of the original expression that caused `__eq__` to be called in the first place. So does this "reversing" of expressions only happens inside `__eq__` functions?

Comment: @M4rtini: No, the reversing doesn't take place for the outer comparison because it never returned `NotImplemented`.

Comment: @M4rtini: note that `x == y` does itself never return `NotImplemented`. Python executes `x.__eq__(y)` and `y.__eq__(x)` as needed, based on what those methods return, but if they both return `NotImplemented` Python raises a `TypeError` instead. The result of the `==` expression is either the first return value from the `__eq__` methods that is not `NotImplemented`, **or** `TypeError` is raised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, thanks for the detailed expleneation as always. So if i understood that correctly. It would actually try to reverse outer comparison, if all inner comparisons returned a `NotImplemented`error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Doesn't the data model state that `__lt__` and `__gt__` are each other's reflection?  So, it does have a "reversed" version, it's just _slightly_ different.  e.g. if I have a class `Foo` with a defined `__gt__` and instance `foo = Foo()`, I can do `foo > 0`, or I can do `0 < foo`.

Comment: @M4rtini: Yes, if the `foo.__eq__()` method itself **explicitly** returns `NotImplemented` then `other.__eq__()` will be tried.

Comment: @mgilson: yes, you are right; `__lt__` is the reflection of `__gt__` and vice-versa; it states there are no `__rlt__` and `__rgt__` methods, which is what I meant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yep.  I figured that's what you meant.  I just wanted to add a little clarification as I suppose someone could find themselves a little confused if you thought they didn't have any reflection at all :)